# Why does my toilet run non-stop?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, hole, leaking

I decided to change out all the internals of the toilet after flapper replacement failed. The toilet is still running non stop.

Oddly enough it only runs from one rim hole even after I changed out and cleaned all the internals.

When I shut off the water, the tank drains about 97% right about even with the flapper. But it's all new inside yet same issue as previous internals.

So I am thinking my set up but how can water run in assuming the flapper seal is good?

Update: the water level was stopping and not overflowing. When I shut off the water the level drains to the flapper. So I decided to change out to another new flapper and it seems to solve the issue. So perhaps I was unlucky and bought a new kit with a bad flapper. Will know in the morning as I shut the water off again.

Comment: give us more details or maybe a photo. What flapper model do you have

Comment: What does "runs from one rim hole" mean? Pics would really help here.

Comment: I think the assumption that the flapper seal is good is probably the problem

Comment: Did you clean or replace the flapper seat/hole that the flapper seals against?  Both need to be in good condition to seal completely.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Blocked holes?  Ever running valve?  Is water running over the top of the overflow pipe?

Comment: How old is the toilet?  Extreme calcification would explain everything in your question.  If so, time for a new one.

Comment: I tried editing your wall o'text into some readable paragraphs - it helps us to better understand what you're trying to say. Please, though, take a moment to pretend you know _nothing_ about your situation and reread your question to see if you understand it from that perspective because that's _our_ perspective. Provide as much detail as you can to help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a reasonably normal toilet there are three possibilities:

1. The flapper isn't sealing completely.
2. The float valve isn't working, and so the water fills the tank until it spills into the overflow pipe next to the flapper.
3. There is a hole somewhere that lets the water through.

Comment: #2 is a good place to check.  If OP changed everything, the float will probably need adjustment, if it allows the water level to be too high.

Comment: #1 Is also a prime suspect. The difference would be whether or not water is running into the overflow pipe. If it is, it's likely the float level adjustment, if not, it's the flapper. I suppose it could be a combination of the two as well.

Comment: Well, it's easy to tell the difference.  Shut off the water and when it stops flowing, look at the level.  If the tank is empty, it's the flapper.  If the tank is full right up to the brim of the overflow, it's the float valve.  OP probably swapped the flapper but did not bother cleaning what the flapper seals against.